# Loading raster data into postgis database

Tags: postgis-2.0

i would like to add raster data to my postgis database. when i try to check if postGIS is responding to requests using the following command psql -c "SELECT PostGIS_Version()" ,i get an error message saying:

> psql: FATAL: role '"blessy" does not exist.

I'm on a 64-bit windows7 os.

Comment: Are you sure that are not two PostgreSQL instances running on different ports? If so take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382926/postgresql-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)